# "Cannot create an abstract class" error when converting API Method from .NET WebForms to .NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I want to create a new WEB API application from my old WebForms application. I copied a POST method to a Controller. My POST method basically receives JSON as a parameter and sends JSON back as a result. Here is the Controller:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Xml;

namespace NewMvcApp.Controllers
{
    public class DataController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Data
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        
        public class APIResponse
        {
            public string data { get; set; }
            public string infoMessage { get; set; }
        }

        [HttpPost, ActionName("request")]
        public System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request(Stream json)
        {
            APIResponse result = new APIResponse();
            
            string message = new StreamReader(json).ReadToEnd();
            XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(message, "parameters");
            
            //do some logic and return 'result'
            
            string jsonSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);

            var iso = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonSerialized);

            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(iso);

            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            
            context.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            context.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Remove("Set-Cookie");

            return context.CreateStreamResponse(memoryStream, "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        }
    }
}
```

I built and deployed this app to a Windows Server. However, when I test the endpoint via POSTMAN

```
https://(mywebsite).com/Data/request
```

I always get this error:

```
Cannot create an abstract class.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Cannot create an abstract class.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:
[MissingMethodException: Cannot create an abstract class.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +142
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +107
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +271

[MissingMethodException: Cannot create an abstract class. Object type 'System.IO.Stream'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +345
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +750
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +466
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +137
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +1082
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +163
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +463
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +68
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +163
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +787
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +163
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +630
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +99
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +68
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +163
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +544
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +970
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +75
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +158
```

My Global.asax.cs:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
```

My POST Method worked on my WebForms application. So I might have missed some configuration. I have tried to find solution with no result. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.message) is an abstract class. So this error makes sense.

You don't have to return a message. You can return your object. Also you don't have to specify Stream parameter of method.

Basicly you can do like this:

```
public class APIRequest
{
    public string parameter1 { get; set; }
    public int parameter2 { get; set; }
}
public class APIResponse
{
    public string data { get; set; }
    public string infoMessage { get; set; }
}
```

in DataController.cs

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("request")]
public APIResponse request(APIRequest req)
{
    var response = new APIResponse
    {
       data = req.parameter2.ToString(),
       infoMessage = req.parameter1
    };
    return response;
}
```

Please take a look [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-5.0).